# TYPO3 [7.6.40] installation on localhost error

Tags: php, typo3

I tried to install TYPO3 [7.6.40] on my localhost using Xampp on Windows. Unfortunately I couldn't find a solution for my problem. I hope that somebody maybe knows the cause to this issue.

**What I did so far:**

- Installed Xampp and started "Apache" and "MySQL"
- Downloaded the TYPO3 [7.6.40] package, unzipped it and copied the files to "C:\xampp\htdocs"
- Inside htdocs I created an empty file called "FIRST_INSTALL"
- With my browser I tried to access http://localhost but only got warnings and errors

#### These are the warnings when I try access http://localhost :

```
Warning: Undefined array key "t3lib/class.t3lib_div.php" in C:\xampp\htdocs\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Utility\GeneralUtility.php on line 5095

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Utility\GeneralUtility.php on line 5095

Warning: Undefined array key "SSL_SESSION_ID" in C:\xampp\htdocs\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Utility\GeneralUtility.php on line 3602

Warning: Undefined array key "HTTPS" in C:\xampp\htdocs\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Utility\GeneralUtility.php on line 3602

Warning: Undefined array key "HTTPS" in C:\xampp\htdocs\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Utility\GeneralUtility.php on line 3602

Warning: Undefined array key "ORIG_SCRIPT_NAME" in C:\xampp\htdocs\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Utility\GeneralUtility.php on line 3408

Warning: Undefined array key "systemLog" in C:\xampp\htdocs\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Utility\GeneralUtility.php on line 5053

Warning: Undefined array key 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Utility\GeneralUtility.php on line 5062

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\TYPO3_ERROR_DLOG" in C:\xampp\htdocs\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Error\ErrorHandler.php:134 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Utility\GeneralUtility.php(3423): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\ErrorHandler->handleError(2, 'Undefined array...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 3423) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Utility\GeneralUtility.php(3566): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getIndpEnv('REQUEST_URI') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Error\AbstractExceptionHandler.php(73): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getIndpEnv('TYPO3_REQUEST_U...') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Error\DebugExceptionHandler.php(50): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\AbstractExceptionHandler->writeLogEntries(Object(Error), 'WEB') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Error\AbstractExceptionHandler.php(45): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\DebugExceptionHandler->echoExceptionWeb(Object(Error)) #5 [internal function]: TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\AbstractExceptionHandler->handleException(Object(Error)) #6 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Error\ErrorHandler.php on line 134
```

#### And some snippets from GeneralUtility.php (Hope this helps somehow):

**GeneralUtility.php line 5094-5097**

```
        // Initialize logging
        if (!$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_div.php']['systemLogInit']) {
            self::initSysLog();
        }
```

**GeneralUtility.php line 3599-3603**

```
 if (self::cmpIP($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $proxySSL)) {
                    $retVal = true;
                } else {
                    $retVal = $_SERVER['SSL_SESSION_ID'] || strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) === 'on' || (string)$_SERVER['HTTPS'] === '1';
                }
```

**GeneralUtility.php line 3403-3408**

```
 switch ((string)$getEnvName) {
            case 'SCRIPT_NAME':
                $retVal = self::isRunningOnCgiServerApi()
                    && ($_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'] ?: $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])
                        ? ($_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'] ?: $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])
                        : ($_SERVER['ORIG_SCRIPT_NAME'] ?: $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

**GeneralUtility.php line 3052-3062**

```
        // Init custom logging
        if (is_array($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_div.php']['systemLog'])) {
            $params = array('initLog' => true);
            $fakeThis = false;
            foreach ($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_div.php']['systemLog'] as $hookMethod) {
                self::callUserFunction($hookMethod, $params, $fakeThis);
            }
        }
        // Init TYPO3 logging
        foreach (explode(';', $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['systemLog'], 2) as $log) {
            list($type, $destination) = explode(',', $log, 3);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 7.6.40 is very old and out of service. your server might be newer than the requirements of this outdated software allow.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was the wrong PHP version. I needed < 8 and had 8.0.9 or so.
I downloaded the correct XAMPP version with PHP 7.xxx and now it's running. I uninstalled the wrong version first.

Now I can start Typo3 installation.

Comment: This seems to be it. I downloaded the correct XAMPP version and it works. Thanks!